# Float prints Int in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I am beginner at programming and I am just writing a very simple program to return the solution of 23/5. My code is below:

```
float res  = 23/5;
printf("%.3f", res);
```

The expected answer is `4.6`, however, the code outputs: `4.000`.

Comment: `23/5` is an integer division and the result is an `int`. You want `23.0/5`.

Comment: So for division in you must input your operands as floats even if they are whole numbers? @Jabberwocky

Comment: @Albert yes. At least one of the operands must be a floating point number.

Comment: Unrelated: prefer `double` when dealing with floating-point values.

Comment: Why is this necessary? As in why doesn't it automatically realise that it shouldn't be output as integer? Sorry I am very new at this. @Jabberwocky

Comment: @pmg I tried with double as well

Comment: @Albert an `int` divided by and `int` is an `int`. These are the rules of the language and this is a very good rule. You don't want your `int`s automatically be transformed into a floating point value (which one BTW, there is `float` and `double`).

Comment: @Jabberwocky, yes that makes sense, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Adding to that, the language does not consider the target type until *after* the computation.

Comment: Could use `float res = 23; res /= 5;`

Comment: @WeatherVane is this a C thing or is this true for all compiled languages?

Comment: I don't know *all* compiled languages and it is better not to make assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting its value to an int

```
float res  = 23.0f/5.0f;
printf("%.3f", res);
```

Comment: to divide float numbers you need to `23.0f/5.0f` otherwise it will be double division